# converting project to maven using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mybatis

I am trying to convert my current application into maven. I am separating the code into different modules.

Its a web application which has

```
 Controller package
 Model package
 services packages 
 DAO packages
 mybatis package which has interface to interact with database
 WEB-INF Folder which contains all jsps inside /jsp folder
```

I created different modules I created a core module which right now has

```
 service package
 DAO Package
 src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
```

I created Model module which has all model classes and I am able to compile it successfully.

Now I am trying to compile mybatis package which is giving me error

```
   /home/.../mybatis/db/mybatis/dao/usersmapper.java :[7,54] error:
   package com.mycom.myproject.mybatis.db.mybatis.model does not exist
```

as usersmapper.class already been created with model module.

So I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

My main pom.xml is

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>mainapp</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--Joda time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>mybatis</module>
</modules>
```

and my model pom is which I am able to compile

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>model</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>model</name>
```

and my mybatis pom which I am not able to compile is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>mybatis</name>

<dependencies>

    <!-- mybaties -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: where is    `com.mycom.myproject.mybatis.model` located ?

Comment: Hi Jiger, its inside mainapp/model/target/classes/com.mycom.myproject.mybatis.model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mybatis`  module is missing the dependency to your model project. A dependency basically includes the classes of another project in the compile classpath of a module.

So, include:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>model</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in your `mybatis` module, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi Blackbuild I am getting this error now  Failed to execute goal on project mybatis: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycom:mybatis:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.mycom:model:jar:1.0 (compile). I think I am very near now

Comment: Hi BlackBuild, I changed the <packaging>jar</packaging> to <packaging>pom</packaging> now it build successfully. Is that correct?

Comment: no, this would in your project not being compiled. Do you get the error in eclipse or while running on the command line?

Comment: I am able to compile when I changed <packaging>jar</packaging> to <packaging>pom</packaging>. Above error(error in first message) I was getting when I compiled in eclipse

Comment: which eclipse version do you use? do you have m2e installed? are the projects maven projects (litte "m" in the upper left corner of the project)? Does it work when calling maven from the commandline?

Comment: yes m2e is installed and it shows little "m" in upper left corner. when I run it from command line it gives some java version error like /usr/lib/jvm/tools.jar not found. I think thats separate issue. something with my java installation that why I am running it through eclipse

Comment: try right-clicking the parent project and selecting run as -> maven install. Does the error happen now? Do the eclipse projects show errors (red x)?

Comment: yes, now its giving me actual error. It works great.. Thansk BlackBuild